# Create Form / Survey using both existing and non-existing Entities (Symfony 3)

Tags: php, mysql, forms, symfony, survey

*I'm trying to create a dynamic Survey / Form Bundle for my App in Symfony 3.2.4 and PHP 5.6.28*

I have 3 entities : Survey / Question / Answer

First step is to create a survey for each user. 
Questions have to be displayed in front with associated answer fields. 
On submit they will be stored in DB, classic.

Questions are already stored in DB Question.table.

I want to make the form work. Display all questions stored in DB and submit answers (associated to questions). Also all answers must be linked to a Survey, so i can display a specific Survey Result (after user complete it)

**Could you help me make it work ?
I can only display one Answer for the last question, i did something wrong in the controller logic or my FormType ?**

*Answer.entity*

```
    <?php

namespace SurveyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Answer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="answer")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SurveyBundle\Repository\AnswerRepository")
 */
class Answer
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="text", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $text;

    /**
     * Id from Company Entity
     *
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SurveyBundle\Entity\Survey", inversedBy="answer", cascade={"persist"})
     *
     */
    private $survey;

    /**
     * Id from Question Entity
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="SurveyBundle\Entity\Question", mappedBy="answer")
     */
    private $question;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set text
     *
     * @param string $text
     *
     * @return Answer
     */
    public function setText($text)
    {
        $this->text = $text;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get text
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getText()
    {
        return $this->text;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSurvey()
    {
        return $this->survey;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $survey
     */
    public function setSurvey($survey)
    {
        $this->survey = $survey;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getQuestion()
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $question
     */
    public function setQuestion($question)
    {
        $this->question = $question;
    }

}
```

*Question.entity*

```
<?php

namespace SurveyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Question
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="question")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SurveyBundle\Repository\QuestionRepository")
 */
class Question
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="text", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $text;


    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->text;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set text
     *
     * @param string $text
     *
     * @return Question
     */
    public function setText($text)
    {
        $this->text = $text;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get text
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getText()
    {
        return $this->text;
    }



}
```

*Survey.entity*

```
<?php

namespace SurveyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Survey
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="survey")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SurveyBundle\Repository\SurveyRepository")
 */
class Survey
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Id from Question Entity
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SurveyBundle\Entity\Question", mappedBy="survey")
     */
    private $question;


    function __construct()
    {
        $this->question = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getQuestion()
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

    /**
     * Id from Answer Entity
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SurveyBundle\Entity\Answer", mappedBy="survey")
     */
    private $answer;

    public function setAnswer($answer)
    {
        $this->answer = $answer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAnswer()
    {
        return $this->answer;
    }

    /**
     * @param Question $question
     */
    public function addQuestion(Question $question)
    {
        $this->question[] = $question;
    }




}
```

*Survey.controller*

```
<?php

namespace SurveyBundle\Controller;

use SurveyBundle\Entity\Survey;
use SurveyBundle\Form\SurveyType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/survey", name="survey")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $questions = $em->getRepository('SurveyBundle:Question')->findAll();

        $survey = new Survey();

        //$ListProduits->setProduits($produits);

        foreach ($questions as $question)
            $survey->addQuestion($question);

        $form = $this->createForm(SurveyType::class, $survey);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

                $em->persist($survey);
                $em->flush();

                $data = $form->getData();

                var_dump($data);

                echo 'OK2';

            }else {
                //ERROR
                trigger_error('Error - Survey hasn\'t been completed - Contact a Wizard');
            }
        }


        return $this->render('SurveyBundle:Default:index.html.twig',  array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

*Survey.FormType*

```
<?php

namespace SurveyBundle\Form;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class SurveyType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            //->add('name','text')
            ->add('question', EntityType::class,
                    'class' => 'SurveyBundle:Question',
                    'mapped' => false,
                    "multiple" => true,
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('q')
                            ->orderBy('q.text', 'ASC');
                    },
            ))
            ->add(
                'answer',
                AnswerType::class
            )
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'SurveyBundle\Entity\Survey'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'referencebundle_survey';
    }


}
```

The formView :
[image: front.survey]

I only have one answer field, just for question 2. I need one for each question.

Also when I try to submit i got this error :

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of
>   the type array, object given, called in
>   .../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 605
>   and defined

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rendering all questions with the multiple=>true statement, but that does not associate an answer with each question. THEN your form renders an answer, so you only see one answer.

I think what you need is a collection of forms, see the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

First build a single form for each question/answer combo, then render the collection of forms from the Survey.FormType.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution thanks to @ehymel

**In my Survey form builder I have now 2 CollectionType** : Question & Answer
Each one has his own FormType.

I did a foreach in my controller to associate Q & A with my Survey Object, and an other one for persisting my answers after submit.

I also reworked a bit my entities relations.

Controller :

```
$questions = $em->getRepository('SurveyBundle:Question')->findAll();

    $survey = new Survey();

    foreach ($questions as $question) {
        $answer = new Answer();
        $survey->getQuestion()->add($question);
        $answer->setQuestion($question);
        $survey->getAnswer()->add($answer);
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(SurveyType::class, $survey);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $survey->setExperience($experience);
            $em->persist($survey);
            $em->flush();

            foreach ($survey->getAnswer() as $answer) {
                $answer->setSurvey($survey);
                $em->persist($answer);
                $em->flush();
            }
        } else {
            //ERROR
            trigger_error('Error - Experience hasn\'t been completed - Contact a Wizard');
        }
    }
```

SurveyType :

```
class SurveyType extends AbstractType{

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */

private $name = 'default_name';

public function getName(){
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName($name){
    $this->name = $name;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add(
            'question',
            CollectionType::class,
            array(
                'entry_type' => QuestionType::class)
        )
        ->add(
            'answer',
            CollectionType::class,
            array(
            'entry_type' => AnswerType::class)
        );
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'SurveyBundle\Entity\Survey'
    ));
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'referencebundle_survey';
}
```

}